# Implementing Multiple Views In RecycleView. is it Possible?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

[I need to implement a Activity like this using Recycle View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9djW.jpg)

I am doing a cash collection application.

The **Name** Field and **Balance** field items are got from Web Service, and each the item is corresponds to a customer. Here each Recycle item has Two **Textviews** and one **EditText** fields. After entering the amount to the each item I need to identify each editText to calculate the total. My question is is this Possible with a Recycle View? I am new to Android developing.

Comment: what is the problem in developing this with recyclerview?

Comment: i am new to android, and i didn't tried Recycle view before..
so i don't know if it is possible or not, because i need to pass each EditText value to WebService api. each item is a customer so every customer has a customer id, so i need to pass each Edittext value along with that customer id .. is it possible with this? :)

Comment: yes it is possible and first try it yourself and if you face any issues then ask a question here

Comment: i tried.. i displayed an array of elements to recycle view. i read the developers article but i didn't understand how to display multiple view in an item and how to access it. thats why i ask question here

Comment: yes of course it is posible...try this: [MultiView RecyclerView](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Heterogenous-Layouts-inside-RecyclerView) you just have to ovveride getItemViewType and just declare how what viewtype you have to have in each position...

Answer (score 0):

Pretty Simple You can make this.. For this You need to create a another layout for each item of it. Make another layout file named `item_list.xml` And design as you have mentioned in that given picture.. You can Use `LInearLayout`, or `CardView` for this.

Answer (score 0):

That is possible.

You just have to specify `viewType` in `onCreateViewHolder`.

Use different layout for different section..

Like if you have header then check `viewType == 1` then `return view_item` `header_item.xml`

if `viewType == 2` then `return view_item` `footer.xml`

else `return view_item` `normal_list_item.xml`

Comment: Thank you.. glad to know that this is possible and,  i need to pass each EditText value to WebService api. each item is a customer so every customer has a customer id, so i need to pass each Edittext value along with that customer id .. is it possible with this?

Comment: It is also possible, just keep reference of viewType for your operation